# Get an static element's position on the body?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the position of an element in the body even when it has `position:static`?

EG: if I have three elements one after another:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

Each element has 25px. I want to able to find the position of element with `id=3`. (it should return 50px)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `offsetTop`

```
document.getElementById('3').offsetTop
```

also `offsetLeft` to get the horizontal position

```
document.getElementById('3').offsetLeft
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dELxU/)